# Find filenames with only one period in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to write a script for my C# project that pulls all base resource files out for translation. Effectively, I want to find `PageName.resx` but not `PageName.fr.resx`. I have tried:

```
dir /s /b *.* | findstr /R ^[a-z]*\.resx$
```

However, this includes the *.fr.resx files, which I do not want. Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will exclude any file with two periods.  You can add another findstr to exclude three periods.

```
dir /s /b /a-d *.* | findstr /v ".*\..*\."
```

Or you can use this will echo only the files with one period.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*) do (
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%x in ("%%~nxa") do if "%%z"=="" echo "%%a"
)
```